Can prisma orm accept a subset of a table's column data
I've started looking into prisma ORM.
I like it so far, and can see potential time savings and increased structure. However, when calling db.table.create, the call fails unless I have passed in every field in the prisma model. Here's the code I'd like to use (return of generatied id etc. and error handling not done yet :)):
export async function POST(event) {
  const data = await event.request.formData()
  const formDataObj = Object.fromEntries(data.entries())

  try {
    await db."table".create({ data: formDataObj });
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: true }), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log ('post error %s on "table"', e.toString());
  }
}

Is there a way to "switch off" this behaviour? I'm using postgresql (if that has any bearing), the table structures are quite dynamic, I've previously used my own code to generate an insert and just leave out fields that are not of particular interest at insert time.
Or maybe I need to grab the prisma model, set the members to whatever is in formData, and set the missing columns to NULL if I have no formData for them?
I'd prefer the first option if possible?

You don't have to provide a value for optional and nullable fields in a create statement. (Neither for an update, either, for that matter.)
You didn't include your Prisma model, but let's use this for example:
model User {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName String
  lastName  String
  email     String?   @unique
  birthDate DateTime?
}

Here, id is required, but auto-generated by the DB. First and last names are required. Email and birthdate are optional so they can be omitted. The minimal statement to create a new user would require only:
await prismaClient.user.create({
  data: {
    firstName: 'Alice',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  },
});


No undefined or no null values required.

Thank you @Perttu Haliseva! That works as you explain. I had omitted the ? after the field type; I didn't realise this option existed; I find the prisma documentation a little tricky to navigate sometimes ...
